# Keep rows from file 1 matching values from file 2 using awk

Tags: shell, awk

Contents of the Main File-

```
$ cat Sort_File2.csv 

'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:13'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L5O'|'5042449534546015801549'   
'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:13'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L5O'|'5042449534546015801549'    
'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:13'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L5Q'|'5042449536906016501541'    
'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:20'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L6I'|'5042449603146028701548'
```

Contents of the File to be Matched to -

```
$ cat DuplicatesEqTo1_f2.csv 

1|'5042449536906016501541'    
1|'5042449603146028701548'
```

I want the `Awk` Statement to Store in File the Rows from `Sort_File2.csv` matching with the values from in the file `DuplicatesEqTo1_f2.csv`.

---

Output I want -

```
'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:13'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L5Q'|'5042449536906016501541'    
'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:20'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L6I'|'5042449603146028701548'
```

---

Note I tried the Below Statement its not working and not returning anything--

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{++a[$2];next} $1 in a' DuplicatesEqTo1_f1.csv Sort_File1.csv
```

Comment: Shouldn't it the last column on the `Sort_file1.csv`? it should be `$4 in a ` or `$NF in a`

Comment: Thanks, that works.. But if suppose i want to have the Column to compare to in the main file as dynamic and i have the column in a variable called $var1.. Then how it will be reflected in the same scenario???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use join for this job.

```
var=5;join -t '|' -1 "$var" -2 2 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 Sort_File2.csv DuplicatesEqTo1_f2.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next} $NF in a' DuplicatesEqTo1_f1.csv Sort_File1.csv
'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:13'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L5Q'|'5042449536906016501541'
'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:20'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L6I'|'5042449603146028701548'
```

#### Notes

1. The field that you want to match is the last on the line, `$NF`, not the first.  Thus replace `$1 in a` with `$NF in a`.
2. It does no harm but it isn't necessary to increment `a[$2]`.  Simply referencing `a[$2]` creates the key in array `a` which is all you need for in order to use the test `$NF in a`.

#### Matching against a column specified by a shell variable

Let' define a shell variable, `var1`, and match against column number `$var1`:

```
$ var1=5
$ awk -F'|' -v col="$var1" 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next} $col in a' DuplicatesEqTo1_f1.csv Sort_File1.csv
'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:13'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L5Q'|'5042449536906016501541'
'SR'|'2017-09-01 00:19:20'|'+05:30'|'1A3LA7015L6I'|'5042449603146028701548'
```

Comment: But if suppose i want to have the Column to compare to in the main file as dynamic and i have the column in a variable called $var1.. Then how it will be reflected in the same scenario???

Comment: @SamratSaha No problem.  See updated answer for variable column solution.